# Failing to parse a fix width text file

Tags: perl

I'm trying to parse a text file that look like this:

```
aaa aaa aaa
111 111 111
bbb bbb bbb
222 222 222
ccc ccc ccc
333 555 666
ddd ddd ddd
444 444 444
```

In order to get a result like this :

```
 aaa aaa111 aaa
 bbb bbb222 bbb
 ccc ccc333 ccc
 ddd ddd444 ddd
```

My code looks like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @array;  
my $flag = "";
my $permit;
my $adrr;
my $descr;
my $str_no;

my $file = 'Permit.txt';
open my $fh, '+<', $file
    or die "Cannot open 'file ' for writing: $!";

while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    chomp($line);
    if ($line =~ /^[abcd]/) {
        $str_no = substr($flag,0,3);
        $permit = substr($line, 0, 3);
        $adrr = substr($line, 4, 3);
        $descr = substr($line, 8, 3);
        if($flag) {
            if ($str_no) {
                $adrr .= $str_no;   
        }       

        }
        push @array, {permi => $permit, adr => $adrr, desc => $descr};
        $flag = ""; 

    } else {
            $flag = $line;
    }
}
print Dumper(\@array);
```

But this pushes all my values from the numbers row down concatenating the first number to the second letters row.

Answer (score 5):

Read the file two lines at a time:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    my @fields  = split;
    my @numbers = split(' ', <DATA>);
    $fields[1] .= $numbers[0];

    print "@fields\n";
}

__DATA__
aaa aaa aaa
111 111 111
bbb bbb bbb
222 222 222
ccc ccc ccc
333 555 666
ddd ddd ddd
444 444 444
```

Output:

```
aaa aaa111 aaa
bbb bbb222 bbb
ccc ccc333 ccc
ddd ddd444 ddd
```